# perror generating unexpected errno value

Tags: c, glibc, errno

I am experiencing an unexpected value of `errno` when using `perror` with `glibc`.  When an non-existent file is specified as `arg[1]` it prints `Error: 2` ( which is`ENOENT`) as expected.  However when the `perror` line below is uncommented it throws error 22 (`EINVAL`) no matter what I pass it.  Can anyone please explain why this is getting set?

EDIT:  Looks like this is some sort of Eclipse bug.  The IDE seems to be causing perror to throw some sort of error, the program works perfectly on the command line, and works perfectly when a correct file is specified in the argument list in Eclipse.  It fails incorrectly when run inside of Eclipse.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
FILE *input_file;
input_file = fopen(argv[argc - 1], "r");
if (!input_file) {
 // perror(argv[argc-1]);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %d\n", errno);
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else {
    fclose(input_file);
}
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the perror() call prints the wrong thing, or that the fprintf prints the wrong thing if you call perror() ?

Comment: Neither.  I'm saying that perror sets errno in an unexpected way.

Comment: @Who ever guaranteed what perror would do to errno? Why call both perror and print the errno? See rlibby's answer below (and be a good fellow and accept it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't rely on the value of `errno` after calling into other library functions, in other words your call to perror() itself may be modifying the value of `errno`  You need to save it in a temporary variable if you want to be able to use it after calls into other library procedures.

```
if (!input_file) {
    int err = errno;
    perror(argv[argc-1]);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %d\n", err);
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Right, there's a rule "the value of `errno` after a library call is unpredictable."  One might think there should be an exception to the rule for the library call `perror`, but this is not in fact guaranteed by POSIX.

Comment: perror printed the error, which for most people is the end of it; it would be a waste for it to preserve errno. I myself always use strerror, never perror, which is ancient and inflexible.

Answer (score 1):

Your program works as expected for me here:

```
$ ./app fkjhsf
Error: 2
```

and with the `perror()` call uncommented:

```
$ ./app asdkfljh
asdkfljh: No such file or directory
Error: 2
```

Maybe the `perror()` call is changing your `errno` for some reason?  What operating system/compiler/library versions are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10
gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)

Answer (score 0):

He's likely running the program without any arguments.

If so, "argv[argc - 1]" will evaluate to garbage.

There should be code to make sure that "argc-1" is within a valid range.

Comment: I'm not, when a correct file is passed into the argument list it runs fine.